# Join query with Angularfire2 and firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Thanks for reading.

I have two Collections in Firestore and I'm using Angularfire2.

I have a collections of "Clients" and a collection of "Jobs". Clients can have a number of Jobs and each job has a linked client.

I've created a component to show a list of *all* the jobs, and I'm trying to pull in the associated client for each job using the Firestore key.

Here's my data:

[image: Client list]

[image: Jobs list]

I have been able to "hack" a solution but it is extremely buggy, and it looses all async - so I might as well write a MySQL backend and forget Firestore - the whole point of using Firestore is it's "live".

```
    public jobs = {};
[...]       
    processData() {

            const clients = [];
             this.clientCollection.ref.get().then((results) => {
              results.forEach((doc) => {
                clients[doc.id] = doc.data();
              });
              const jobs = {};
              this.jobsCollection.ref.get().then((docSnaps) => {
                docSnaps.forEach((doc) => {
                  jobs[doc.id] = doc.data();
                  jobs[doc.id].id = doc.id;
                  jobs[doc.id].clientData = clients[doc.data().client];
                });
                this.jobs = jobs;
              });

            });

          }
```

This works up to a point - but it strips out the async.

**Key question: is there any way of doing a "join" as we would in an SQL database to pull these two data sets together? And is there a way of doing it in a way that will keep the async nature of the data?**

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for this yet? I encountered exactly the same issue as you, I tried use Observable.combineLatest() as mentioned by below answer, but not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `Promise.all()` to fetch multiple promises into one object. Here is a revised version of your method that should give the desired result if I am understanding your question correctly:

```
  async processData() {
    const clientCollection = await firebase.firestore().collection(`clients`).get();
    const jobsCollection = await firebase.firestore().collection(`jobs`).get();
    const clients = [];
    clients.push(clientCollection);
    clients.push(jobsCollection);
    const res = await Promise.all(clients);
    // res should equal a combination of both querySnapshots
  }
```

I just recreated the collection variables to show what to add to the array, but `Promise.all()` takes in an array of promises and resolves all of them into one array as the `get()` method in `firestore` is a Promise. This is also using async/await. Hope this can be of help!

EDIT:

Since you are using AngularFire2, you should use their method for this.

In you component you are going to want to import the `angularfire2/firestore` module and use the `Observable` methods they provide:

first import the module: `import { AngularFireStore } from 'angularfire2/firestore'`;

then provide it to your constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFireStore
  ) { }
```

Then you could use `Observable.combineLatest()` to receive all the data at one time:

```
  clients$: Observable<any[]>;
  clients: any[];

  jobs$: Observable<any[]>;
  jobs: any;

  joined: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clients$ = this.getCollection('clients');
    this.jobs$ = this.getCollection('jobs');
    this.joined = Observable.combineLatest(this.clients$, this.jobs$);
    this.joined.subscribe(([clients, jobs]) => {
      this.clients = clients;
      this.jobs = jobs;
    });
  }


  getCollection(collectionName) {
    return this.firestore.collection(`${collectionName}`).valueChanges();
  }
```

In your markup you would just loop the data using `*ngFor`:

`<div *ngFor="let client of clients">{{ client.name }}</div>`

This way, your component will be listening for new data once firestore has the data and it will all come in at one time so you don't have nested subscriptions that are vulnerable to creating multiple subscriptions. Hope this can be of help.

Comment: Indulge me here... How would I access the data in the template with this method?

Comment: Hey I just made edits to the answer that may simplify this.

Comment: I can't see where you relate clients and jobs.

Answer (score 1):

late for solutions but after 4 hours searching I found this solution library its very useful for join collection and get data.

main resource : https://github.com/AngularFirebase/133-firestore-joins-custom-rx-operators

first create one type script file

file name : collectionjoin.ts

```
import { combineLatest, pipe, of, defer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';



  export const leftJoinDocument = (afs: AngularFirestore, field, collection) => {
  return source =>
    defer(() => {
      // Operator state
      let collectionData;
      const cache = new Map();

      return source.pipe(
        switchMap(data => {
          // Clear mapping on each emitted val ;
          cache.clear();

          // Save the parent data state
          collectionData = data as any[];

          const reads$ = [];
          let i = 0;
          for (const doc of collectionData) {
            // Skip if doc field does not exist or is already in cache
            if (!doc[field] || cache.get(doc[field])) {
              continue;
            }

            // Push doc read to Array
            reads$.push(
              afs
                .collection(collection)
                .doc(doc[field])
                .valueChanges()
            );
            cache.set(doc[field], i);
            i++;
          }

          return reads$.length ? combineLatest(reads$) : of([]);
        }),
        map(joins => {
          return collectionData.map((v, i) => {
            const joinIdx = cache.get(v[field]);
            return { ...v, [field]: joins[joinIdx] || null };
          });
        }),
        tap(final =>
          console.log(
            `Queried ${(final as any).length}, Joined ${cache.size} docs`
          )
        )
      );
    });
};
```

after that in your homepage.ts or any page typescript file.

```
     import {
        AngularFirestore,
        AngularFirestoreCollection,
        AngularFirestoreDocument,
        } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
    
    jobs: any
    constructor( public afStore: AngularFirestore ) { }
    
        
        this.afStore.collection('Jobs').valueChanges().pipe(
            leftJoinDocument(this.afStore, 'client', 'Clients'),
            shareReplay(1)
            ).subscribe((response) => {
                this.products = response;
        })
```

in this step we are passing three arguments

1. this.afStore = this is object of lib.
2. 'client' = this is key/id of jobs collections
3. 'Clients' = this is collection name which we are join.

now last step Display result

```
 <ion-list lines="full" *ngFor="let job of Jobs">
        <ion-item button  detail>             
          <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">{{ job.Name }}</ion-label>
          <p>{{ job.Clients.companyName}}</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

finally this code given two collection record.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**After trying multiple solution I get it done with RXJS combineLatest, take operator. Using map function we can combine result.**

Might not be an optimum solution but here its solve your problem.

```
combineLatest(
    this.firestore.collection('Collection1').snapshotChanges(),
    this.firestore.collection('Collection2').snapshotChanges(),
    //In collection 2 we have document with reference id of collection 1
)
.pipe(
    take(1),
).subscribe(
    ([dataFromCollection1, dataFromCollection2]) => {

        this.dataofCollection1 = dataFromCollection1.map((data) => {
            return {
                id: data.payload.doc.id,
                ...data.payload.doc.data() as {},
            }
            as IdataFromCollection1;
        });

        this.dataofCollection2 = dataFromCollection2.map((data2) => {
            return {
                id: data2.payload.doc.id,
                ...data2.payload.doc.data() as {},
            }
            as IdataFromCollection2;
        });

        console.log(this.dataofCollection2, 'all feeess');

        const mergeDataFromCollection =
            this.dataofCollection1.map(itm => ({
                payment: [this.dataofCollection2.find((item) => (item.RefId === itm.id))],
                ...itm
            }))

        console.log(mergeDataFromCollection, 'all data');
    },
```