# Firebase - Return multiple queries as a collectionData?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire

The [`"in"`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) operator works when the number of equality is 10 or less. When it is larger than 10, I will partition the array into multiple sub-arrays of length 10 and initialize multiple query requests.

When the length is less than 10, I am simply using `q` as the query request and returning `return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' });`. However, when I have `q0`, `q1`, etc., I don't know how to return them all the same way as if returning `q`.

The question is how to return `q0`, `q1`, ... using the same syntax as just returning `q`?

```js
constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {
}

getUserChats() {
    const userId = '12345678910';
    const userRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${userId}`);
    return docData(userRef).pipe(
        switchMap((data) => {
            let userChats = data.chats;
            let chatsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'chats');
            if (userChats.length <= 10) {
                //use the query normally as the 'in' operator has a limit of 10
                let q = query(chatsRef, where(documentId(), 'in', userChats));
                return collectionData(q, { idField: 'id' });
            } else {
                //breakdown the userChats array into sub-arrays of length 10
                //it is hardcoded for proof-of-concept
                let q0 = query(chatsRef, where(documentId(), 'in', userChats.slice(0, 10)));
                let q1 = query(chatsRef, where(documentId(), 'in', userChats.slice(10, 20)));
                //...
                //how to combine q0 and q1?
                return collectionData(????????????????, { idField: 'id' });
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join query with Angularfire2 and firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346296/join-query-with-angularfire2-and-firestore)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I don't know because I am using Firebase V9 and the answer was given in the previous version of Firebase. I don't know how to convert the old syntax to the new one.

Comment: Are you using AngularFire?

Comment: Yes V9, the import is from `@angular/fire/firestore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I have come up with:

- Divide the data into segments of size `10` (the last segment might have `10` or less)
- For each query, use the `in` operator for each segment, which contains at most `10` equalities
- Each query will be stored in an array of queries
- `collectionData` is then used for each query in the array, which returns an observable
- All the observables will be stored inside an array of observable
- The function `combineLatest` from RxJS is then used with the array of observables and it then returned

```js
  getUserChats() {
    const userId = 'aabbccdd';
    const userRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${userId}`);
    return docData(userRef).pipe(
      switchMap((data) => {
        if (data && data.chats) {
          const userChats = data.chats;
          const chatsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'chats');
          let queries = [];
          if (userChats.length !== 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < userChats.length; i += 10) {
              let q: Query<DocumentData> = query(
                chatsRef,
                where(documentId(), 'in', userChats.slice(i, i + 10))
              );
              queries.push(q);
            }

            let observablesData: Observable<DocumentData[]>[] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
              let x = collectionData(queries[i], { idField: 'id' });
              observablesData.push(x);
            }
            return combineLatest(observablesData);
          }
        }
        return [null];
      })
    );
  }
```

To test the function, ensure to check for the `null` case, as this will thrown an exception:

```js
this.chatService
      .getUserChats()
      .pipe()
      .subscribe((result: FirebaseChatroom[]) => {
        if (result !== null) {
          result = result.flat();
          //do something with result...
        }
      });
```